# Close thread-local resource after thread finishes

Tags: java, multithreading, realm

I'm trying to implement Realm database in my app. Since my app is using several ThreadPools (that need to query the Realm) and Realm docs state clearly that Realm instance and objects cannot be passed between threads, I've set a ThreadFactory in my class (t being ThreadPoolExecutor):

```
        t.setThreadFactory(new ThreadFactory() {
            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                return new RealmThread();
            }
        });
```

to initialize a Realm with RealmThread that looks like this:

```
public class RealmThread extends Thread {
    Realm realm = null;

    public Realm getRealm() {
        if(realm==null) {
            realm = Realm.getInstance(my_app_context);
        }
        return realm;
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        try{
            if(realm!=null)
                realm.close();
            Logger.d("[XThread] Closing thread-local Realm");
        }catch(Throwable t){
            throw t;
        }finally{
            super.finalize();
        }
    }
}
```

With finalizer, since Realms need to be closed... But... You should never count on finalizers, right? So how would I cleanup after thread finished without the finalizer? Is there any other way?

Note: getting Realm instance and closing it after each operation doesn't work, as it seems close sometimes happens after next open!

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot put `realm.close()` as the last statement in your run `method``?

Comment: Nope, besides the one mentioned earlier - when I tried to close the Realm after each operation, sometimes, after obtaining new instance of default Realm, it threw "Realm Already Closed" (or something similar) exception, probably because close() happens in async manner.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are getting the Realm instance in the constructor. The constructor will most likely be called on the Main thread. Try putting it in your run method instead?

Comment: Aaah, good point. Maybe I'll do it lazy way - obtain Realm on first access. But still that doesn't solve the main problem of freeing it.